# Calling TextChanged Event using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server-2008, populate, autocompleteextender

I am working on a project in which i have used `autocomplete extender` with textbox. And on textxhanged event of that textbox i am populating two dropdown which were initially empty. Now the thing is i have two panel. I am copying data from one panel to another. All the attributes of both `panels` are same. Now the thing is that i am having two radio button one is for copying data from panel one and other is for new data insert. Now if i choose copy option then it is copying all the values but at that those two `dropdown` stay empty. And i am doing it by using javascript. Please suggest me or guide me to solve this problem. Is it possible to call `textchanged` event of textbox using javascript??

Note: I am populating dropdowns and autocompleteextender using database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onchange event of textbox in javascript.

Comment: i know that but i want to call the text change event which is at coding side. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Try this,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = xyz;

          function xyz() {

              document.getElementById('<%= button1.ClientID %>').click();

          }
    <script>
    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="textbox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" style=" display:none;" onclick="button1_Click"  />
```

CodeBehind:

```
    protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1_TextChanged(null, null)
    }
    protected void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //your code here
    }
```

Comment: its not working.... as i have used onClientClick as well ..

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, GetType(), "OnClientClick", "OnClientClick(); return false;", true);

Comment: Call it from server side in button1_Click event

Comment: I hope it works for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can you __doPostBack javascript function from asp.net with the name of text box for which you want to raise this event.